# Keras package installation

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, theano

I am trying to install Keras package to use the machine learning tools.
Unfortunately I am unable to do so. I have theano installed. And I have tensorflow installed in a separate environment in python 3.5 but I am trying to use python 2.7 for this. Is that the problem?

```
C:\Users\User>pip install tensorflow   
Collecting tensorflow   
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )   
No matching distribution found for tensorflow   

C:\Users\User>pip install keras
Requirement already satisfied: keras in c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages   
Requirement already satisfied: theano in c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from keras)   
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from keras)   
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from keras)   
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from theano->keras)   
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from theano->keras)
```

I am still having import error saying no tensorflow back-end found when i try to import keras

Comment: It says that keras is already installed, so, what's the actual problem?

Comment: Have you actually tried to user Keras? It seems it is already installed, just use Theano con your `config` file

Comment: Yea i am unable to import keras. Says tensorflow backed not found

Comment: If you are trying to install keras + tensorflow for python 2, then it will not work as tensorflow supports python 3. So, If you are using python 2 then better use Theano as backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow [officially](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) only supports Python 3.5.x on Windows. For python 2 you need to switch your backend to Theano. You can change the Keras backend to Theano in `C:\Users\username\.keras\keras.json`. Also check [this](https://keras.io/backend/) documentation.

If you want to switch to another keras backend in the script you can also use the following code:

```
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = "theano" #or "tensorflow"
import keras
```